# How to find all argmax in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I have a 2 dimensional NumPy ndarray.

```
array([[  0.,  20.,  -2.],
   [  2.,   1.,   0.],
   [  4.,   3.,  20.]])
```

How can I get all indices of the maximum elements? So I would like as output array([0,1],[2,2]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) on *max-equality mask* -

```
np.argwhere(a == a.max())
```

Sample run -

```
In [552]: a   # Input array
Out[552]: 
array([[  0.,  20.,  -2.],
       [  2.,   1.,   0.],
       [  4.,   3.,  20.]])

In [553]: a == a.max() # Max equality mask
Out[553]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [554]: np.argwhere(a == a.max()) # array of row, col indices of max-mask
Out[554]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

If you are working with floating point numbers, you might want to use some tolerance there. So, with that consideration, you could use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) that has some default absolute and relative tolerance values. This would replace the earlier `a == a.max()` part, like so -

```
In [555]: np.isclose(a, a.max())
Out[555]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```